# send e-mails via smtp without authentification

Tags: emails, error, logs

I try to send e-mails via SMTP without authentification and I'm getting the following error:

> There was an error testing your email settings.

I checked my setup on https://www.smtper.net/. No problems!

I read through the [troubleshooting-email-errors](https://craftcms.com/guides/troubleshooting-email-errors) page but still found no solution for my problem.

Why can't I find a log under *craft/storage/runtime/logs/craft.log*. This file does not exist on my system. There is only *craft/storage/logs/web.log*.

When I use another SMTP server (with auth) everything works as expected. Any ideas on how to find out what's going on here?

Comment: Is there any related errors being logged in `craft/storage/logs/web.log`?

Comment: All I get there is:

[info][yii\mail\BaseMailer::send] Sending email "This is a test email from Craft" to "myname@mycompany.de"

[info][yii\swiftmailer\Mailer::sendMessage] Sending email "This is a test email from Craft" to "myname@mycompany.de"

[warning][application] Error sending email: Connection could not be established with host _mycompany-de_.mail.protection.outlook.com [Connection timed out #110]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that protection.outlook.com simply doesn't allow un-authenticated connections, because well... I'm sure they relay enough SPAM with authenticated connections, much less unauthenticated ones.

Comment: This was my guess too. But why does the same configuration work on smtper.net? As long as the sender e-mail is in our domain everything works fine.

Comment: Itt's the official way to send e-mails with office 365: https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3

Comment: Where are you seeing that? "Requirements for SMTP client submission
Authentication : You must be able to configure a username and password to send emails on the device."

Comment: I'm trying to do [Option 2, Direct send](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3#option-2-send-mail-directly-from-your-printer-or-application-to-office-365-direct-send) and I tested the setup successfully in an other environment.